# How to remove dynamically added jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, dom

I am working with C# and i am loading a jquery file 1.8.1 in the layout, but there is a module pulling through which is adding another jquery file 1.6.1 is there any way for me to remove it without physically going in and remove it so i need to remove it dynamically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use follwing function and pass filename you want to remove

```
function removeScript(filename){

    var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName('script')
    for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
    if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src')!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute('src').indexOf(filename)!=-1)
        allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but should i only change filename? to what ? where the file is pulling from ? Tried this but is not working

    function removeScript(/Scripts/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js)

Comment: just try removeScript('jquery.min.js')

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet for removing `script` file dynamically.

```
$("script[src='jquery-1.6.1.js']").remove()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but this is not working i have the following

$("script[src='/Scripts/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js']").remove();